# Real-time web communication (embedded ljnux)

Tags: c++, linux, web-services, sockets, xilinx

I want to make a smart little project where I receive data from an embedded linux (petalinux) into a phonegap app (Android).

The question is, what type of protocols are prefered?

I recently read about socket io and it looks great.

But how can I get the app to communicate from for example c or c++ to javascript and html?

The data will probably be stored into a sqlite database inside the embedded linux, or will someone prefer a better real time database system (RTDBS)?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: So, let me understand, you want real-time communication across the internet to a web server and also database access.  Good luck, as internet reliability access and speed has a lot of dependencies.  For example, a coax connection would be faster than a DSL connection.  What happens if the server is busy?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sorry for not mentioning that the embedded linux platform will operate as the web server, and the communication will happen through wireless network (no need for internet access).